# "such as", "as", or ... in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, such

Reliable processes have ***only*** two characteristic features, namely A and B.

> 1. I Will examine them, considering **their characteristic features such
>      as** A and B.
> 2. I will examine them, considering **such characteristic
>      features of them as** A and B.
> 3. I will examine them, considering **their characteristic features as** A and B.
> 4. I will examine them, considering **such characteristic features as** 
>      A and B.

I think "such as" is **always** used when we want to mention things among others, it means the same as "for example". Is that so? I mean is "such as" *always* used when there can be other cases too.

This is what [this dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=such%20as%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIR762IR762&oq=such%20as%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.2281j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) says:

> 1. for example. "wildflowers such as daisies and red clover"
> 2. of a kind that; like. "an event such as we've shared"

So when we are not talking about kind, "such as" means the same as "for example".

Now, because there is only two characteristic features, can I use "such as" like in my first sentence?

Or can we say that the second sentence does not the problem?

What about the third sentence? Does it have the same problem?

Finally, the fourth sentence does not say that such features are characteristic of processes. Is that obvious from the context? If so, doesn't it have the problem in the first sentence?

Can you suggest better alternative for the bold part?

Comment: Please come up with a more accurate and descriptive title. Your current one "How to say what I want to?" could refer to absolutely *anything*.

Comment: And a tiny bit of research wouldn't go amiss either.

Comment: "... it means the same as "for example". Is that so?" -- Yes.

Comment: See also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Edited!

Answer (score -2):

> I Will examine them, considering their characteristic **features** <strike>such as</strike> A and B.

You do not need the phrase *such as*. OTOH, *feature* needs to be in plural.

HTH.

*meta:* I see this as a grammar question. If it is considered writing advice, it would be OT.